# Difference between Virtual machine and instance

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-platform

I have been gone through Google cloud services for my project requirement.  I am little bit confused the terms used in Google cloud.  I would like to know what is the difference between VM and instance or both are same?  If both terms are difference, in terms of what?

As far as my understanding VM is also known as instance.  It means if I am creating one instance, i am creating one VM.  If I am creating multi VM, that means I am creating more than 1 instance.  Am I right?

I am trying to find correct explanation across google search.  But unfortunately, I couldn't get.  Really appreciate if anyone help me to understand the above confusion.  Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why the question has been minus voted.  Would be better if someone help me to understand the technology rather than putting down vote...  Hope that make sense...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@vasethvan I think your understanding is generally correct. For all practical purposes on Google cloud you may use the terms interchangeably. 
*An instance is a virtual machine (VM) hosted on Google's infrastructure.* per documentation at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/

In general you can run a VM on Google cloud or any other cloud or even your own desktop. Per wikipedia  *In computing, a virtual machine (VM) is an emulation of a particular computer system*

Cloud providers (like google) allow you to define Virtual Machine "images" or use pre-defined images which can be used to create one or more Virtual Machine instances that look alike. An VM image is a blue print of a machine emulation and instances are live running copies of that image. In practise often VM and instance terms are use interchangeably.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  So as you said, I can't create more than one instance under single VM.  Because VM means nothing but "instance" in Google platform. Right?

Comment: @Vasethvan Yes you can't run multiple instances as one VM. However in case you want to run multiple VMs that look alike then you should look at this documentation https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images

Comment: Great VVS.  Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: What is really confusing is that in some of the docs it tells one to SSH into one's instance from the command line of the instance!?
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-compute-engine-docker#deploy_backend

I really don't understand this.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual machine is a fully contained object using emulated hardware to provide services. An "instance" is a differential copy of a virtual machine. The source virtual machine for any "instance" is the image from which it is deployed.